# About local.php configuration and location for ZF2 application

Tags: php, configuration, zend-framework2

I have to take over a ZF2 PHP application which has not been developed by me initially.

I have been given a `local.php` file from the former developer. It contains some configuration elements.

1. I believe I should put this copy in `/config/autoload`, correct?
2. Do I need to perform an extra step to have it loaded by the application, if yes which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I believe I should put this copy in /config/autoload, correct?

Correct.

> Do I need to perform an extra step to have it loaded by the application, if yes which?

You shouldn't need to do anything. The ZF2 skeleton application (which is usually used as the basis for all ZF2 apps) does this by default. The relevant code is here: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/application.config.php#L29 - so you can see if your application has something similar.

Comment: It has something similar (identical in fact). Thanks.